# All styling is being removed from tables

Tags: formatting

I insert a table in TinyMCE.
I open table properties and set the width to 300px.
The table appears as 300 pix in editor.
I save and exit out of TinyMCE.
The table in the published document is also 300 px.
So far, so good.

I now go back into the document to edit some more.
All the table properties are now blank, and table has resized to fit its content.

Any ideas?

I think I am running Version: 5.10.9

I tried table_sizing_mode:fixed in init